# Check existence of a node under a repeating node in XML using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have the following XML,

```
<Root>
  <Node>
    <Child>ch</Child>
    <Child>ch1</Child>
  </Node>

  <Node>
    <Child>ch2</Child>
    <Child>ch3</Child>
  </Node>
```

I want to check if all the nodes in the XML have at least one child node.
If I use boolean(//Node/Child) it will check the whole XML and won't complain if any Node doesn't. have a Child node.
If I use a predicate to mention the position, it works -
boolean(//Node[1]/Child).

Thanks
Sugata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible by counting `Nodes` with a `Child` count equal to zero

`not(count(//Node[count(Child) = 0]) > 0)`

Given

```
<Root>
  <Node>
    <Child>ch</Child>
    <Child>ch1</Child>
  </Node>

  <Node>
    <Child>ch2</Child>
    <Child>ch3</Child>
  </Node>
  <Node/>
</Root>
```

Test failed, there are empty `Node` elements. In other words, the count of empty elements is greater than zero.

```
xmllint --xpath 'not(count(//Node[count(Child) = 0]) > 0)' test.xml; echo
false
```

Removing `<Node/>`

```
xmllint --xpath 'not(count(//Node[count(Child) = 0]) > 0)' test.xml; echo
true
```

If 2 empty node exist

```
xmllint --xpath 'count(//Node[count(Child) = 0])' test.xml; echo
2
```

Answer (score 2):

A solid XPath-2.0 solution would be using a [quantified expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-quantified-expressions) like this:

```
every $x in /Root/Node satisfies count($x/*)
```

Here the fact is used that all values greater than zero for the `count(...)` function are interpreted as TRUE. Explicitly, it would be `count($x/*) > 0`.